# What to bake into an AWS AMI and what to provision using cloud-init?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami, packer, cloud-init

I'm using AWS Cloudformation to setup numerous elements of network infrastructure (VPCs, SecurityGroups, Subnets, Autoscaling groups, etc) for my web application. I want the whole process to be automated. I want click a button and be able to fire up the whole thing.

I have successfully created a Cloudformation template that sets up all this network infrastructure. However the EC2 instances are currently launched without any needed software on them. Now I'm trying to figure out how best to get that software on them.

To do this, I'm creating AMIs using [**Packer.io**](https://packer.io/). But some people have instead urged me to use Cloud-Init. What heuristic should I use to decide what to bake into the AMIs and/or what to configure via Cloud-Init?

For example, I want to preconfigure an EC2 instance to allow me (`saqib`) to login without a password from my own laptop. Thus the EC2 must have a user. That user must have a home directory. And in that home directory must live a file `.ssh/known_hosts` containing encrypted codes. Should I bake these directories into the AMI? Or should I use cloud-init to set them up? And how should I decide in this and other similar cases?

Comment: you need puppet or chef to do the automation job with `user data` defined in CloudFormation.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain what I should put into the AMI?? How do I decide if something should be in the AMI or be configured via `user data`?

Comment: AWS have a comprehensive page discussing the options https://aws.amazon.com/answers/configuration-management/aws-ami-design/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I like to separate out machine provisioning from environment provisioning.

In general, I use the following as a guide:

**Build Phase**

- Build a Base Machine Image with something like Packer, including all software required to run your application. Create an AMI out of this.
- Install the application(s) onto the Base Machine Image creating an Application Image. Tag and version this artifact. Do not embed environment specific stuff here like database connections etc. as this precludes you from easily reusing this AMI across different environment runtimes.
- Ensure all services are stopped

**Release Phase**

- Spin up an environment consisting of the images and infra required, using something like CFN.
- Use Cloud-Init `user-data` to *configure* the application environment (database connections, log forwarders etc.) and then *start* the applications/services

This approach gives the greatest flexibility and cleanly separates out the various concerns of a continuous delivery pipeline.

Comment: An old answer, but I had a recent issue where I used to build entirely from scratch. Unfortunately, AWS introduced an issue with dbus and it no longer worked. Unfortunately, this base image had this bug. Now I do exactly this to ensure my server is as expected, and this also speeds up deployment.

Answer (score 5):

One of the important factors that determines how you should assemble servers, AMIs, and infrastructure planning is to answer the question:  In production, how fast will I need a new instance launched?

The answer to this question will determine how much you bake into the AMI vs. how much you build after boot.

**NOTE:** My experience is with Chef Server so I will use Chef terminology but the concepts are the same for any other configuration management stack.

The general rule of thumb is to treat your "Infrastructure as Code". This means think about the process of launching instances, creating users on that machine, and the process of managing a known_hosts files and SSH keys the same as you would your application code. Being able to track the changes to Infrastructure in source code makes management easier, redeployments, and even CI much easier.

[This Chef Introduction](http://gettingstartedwithchef.com/first-steps-with-chef.html) covers the terminology in Chef of Cookbooks, Recipes, Resources, and more. It shows you how to build a simple LAMP stack, and how you can relaunch it just as easily with one command.

So given the example in your question, at a high level I would do the following:

- Launch a base Ubuntu Linux AMI (currently 14.04) with a Cloudformation script.
- In the UserData section of the Instance configuration, boot strap the Chef Client Install process.
- Run a Recipe to create a user.
- Run a Recipe to create the known_hosts file for the user

Tools like Chef are used because you are able to break down the infrastructure into small blocks of code performing specific functions. There are numerous Cookbooks already [built and available](https://supermarket.chef.io/) that perform the basic building blocks of creating services, installing software packages, etc.

All that being said, there are some times when you have to deviate from best practices in the interest of your specific domain and requirements. There may be situations where given all the advantages of a infrastructure management you will still need to bake items into the AMI.

Let's pretend your application does image processing and has a requirement to use ImageMagick. Let's assume that you will need to build ImageMagick from source. If you were to do this via Chef Recipes this could add another 7 minutes of just compiling ImageMagick to the normal instance boot time. If waiting 10-12 minutes is too long for a new instance to come online then you may want to consider baking your own AMI that has ImageMagick already compiled and installed.

This is an acceptable solution but you should keep in mind that managing your own fleet of pre-baked AMIs adds additional infrastructure overhead. You will need to keep your custom AMIs updated as new AMIs are released, you expand to different instance types and to different AWS Regions.